# Show that max $\{f,g\}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let max $\{f,g\}$ be the function defined by max $\{f,g\}(x)$ = max $\{f(x),g(x)\}$, for $x \in E$ show that max $\{f,g\}$ is continuous.

How do i use the definition of $\epsilon$, $\delta$ to show this provided that $f,g$ are both continuous function.

Comment: $f,g:E \to ?$ ? What is $E$ ? a normed space ? a metric space ? (is it even metrizable ? but since you talk about $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof we imagine that it is)

Comment: E is a common domain

Comment: See also: [If $f,g$ are continuous at $a$, show that $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ and $k(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ are also continuous at $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675481)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ hassle, for all $\epsilon>0$ you get $\delta_f$ and $\delta_g$, and you simply choose $\delta_{\max\{f,g\}}\mathrel{:=}\min \{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$.

Of course, it may be simpler to prove that $x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous and then use the trick by **Mario G**, but the beauty is in the eye of beholder, right? :-)

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:**

$$\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}+\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have continuous $f_k$, $k=1,...,p$. Let $\psi(x) = \max_k f_k(x)$.

Choose $x$ and let $\epsilon>0$, and find $\delta>0$ such that
$-\epsilon < f_k(x)-f_k(y) < \epsilon$ for all $y \in B(x,\delta)$.

Rewrite as $f_k(x) < \epsilon + f_k(y) \le \epsilon +\psi(y)$, and now take the
$\max$ of the left hand side to get
$\psi(x) < \epsilon +\psi(y)$, or $\psi(x)-\psi(y) < \epsilon$.

Repeating for the other inequality gives
$-\epsilon < \psi(x)-\psi(y) < \epsilon$ for all $y \in B(x,\delta)$,
and so $\psi$ is continuous.

Comment: Why are you able to take the max of the left side and preserve the inequality? What if $\psi(x)$ gets larger or equal to $\epsilon + \psi(y)$ because of some function $f_k(x)$?

Comment: Take the max of the left and forget about the middle...